# Underscore as well to regular expression

Tags: regex

I need alpha numeric string with hyphen (`-`) and underscore (`_`). but `-` and `_` can't come alone. There must be some aplha or alpha numeric text with `-` or `_`.

```
abc- allowed
abc_abc-xyz allowed
abc896 allowed
89abc allowed
abc_ not allowed
abc- not allowed
- not allowed
_not allowed
-- not allowed
________ --- not allowed
```

this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

expression do all the things as mentioned above but with `-` I want to add `_` underscore as well. And `-` and `_` can't come at the beginning or at the end.

Comment: Can the string start with a - or _? e.g. _abc or -abc (nvm, you answered it in an update)

Comment: You have both `abc- allowed` and `abc- not allowed` in your examples, so which is it?

Comment: Looks like it's not allowed, since _"and - and _ cant come at the beginning or at the end"_.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would write this:

```
^(?![-_])[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?<![-_])$
```

Here is a rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/7biWZhiiVn

The `^[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+$` would be a string that only contains the characters you want.  The lookahead and lookbehind make sure that the string does not begin or end with a `-` or `_`.

You could probably change `[-a-zA-Z0-9_]` to `[-\w]` since `\w` is usually equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, but Unicode options can change the meaning to include letters from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to it:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]([-_]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

A better one could be:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]([-_]+[0-9a-zA-Z]|[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

Comment: This will not match a single character input

Comment: You're allowing space & punctuation at the start of the expression.

Comment: This is prone to catastrophic backtracking for a string with lots of letters/numbers with a `-` or `_` at the end, for example `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Comment: This requires at least three characters, and would allow something like `%a&`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite it as:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: This is prone to catastrophic backtracking for a string with lots of letters/numbers with a `-` or `_` at the end, for example `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-` ([rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/OZjvNLTOwI)).

Answer (score 0):

This will allow a single `-` and/or `_` to appear in either order, but not together. Also allows straight alphanumeric:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[-_]{0,1}[^-_]+[-_]{0,1}[^-_]+$
```

This alternative also seems to work:

```
^[^-_]+[-_]{0,1}[^-_]+[-_]{0,1}[^-_]+$
```